# Yii Using mongo DB and MySQL at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, security, mongodb, yii

I'm staring to build a system for working with native languages, tags and such data in Yii Framework.

I already choose MongoDB for storing my data as I think it feets nicelly and will get better performance with less costs (the database will have huge amounts of data).

My question regards user authentication, payments, etc... This are sensitive bits of information and areas where I think the data is relational.

So:
1. Would you use two different db systems? Should I need them or I'm I complicating this?
2. If you recommend the two db approach how would I achieve that in Yii?

Thanks for your time!

PS: I do not intend this question to be another endless discussion between the relational vs non-relational folks. Having said that I think that my data feets mongo but if you have something to say about that go ahead ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be interested in [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jwage/opensky-infrastructure) on OpenSky's infrastructure, where MongoDB is used alongside MySQL. Mongo was utilized mainly for CMS-type data where a flexible schema was useful, and they relied upon MySQL for transactions (e.g. customer orders, payments). If you end up using the Doctrine library, you'll find that the [ORM](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2) (for SQL databases) and [MongoDB ODM](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm) share a similar API, which should make the experimentation process easier.

I wouldn't shy away from using MongoDB to store user data, though, as that's often a record that can benefit from embedded document storage (e.g. storing multiple billing/shipping addresses within a single user document). If anything, Mongo should be flexible enough to enable you to develop your application without worrying about schema changes due to evolving product requirements. As those requirements become more clear, you'll be able to make a decision based on the app's performance needs and types of database queries you end up needing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in using multiple databases (if you really need), many big websites are using multiple databases so go a head and start your project.

Comment: Mixing NoSQL and relational dbs is never a good thing. Unless there is a real need. You usually go all out on NoSQL or you don't. At my company we have a large website, we use MySQL for the data, but we use mongodb GridFS to store files. Only to store files as MongoDB GridFs is perfect for this.